# Solving digit-only captcha

Tags: command-line, ocr, captcha, tesseract, digits

There is a captcha which I'm trying to solve, I know its always digits.
When i try the command `tesseract cap.png cap` it returns empty page !!!

When I try command `tesseract cap.png cap -psm 6 digits && cat cap.txt` it returns:

```
[root@usa1 ~]# tesseract cap.png cap -psm 7 digits && cat cap.txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00dev with Leptonica
Info in pixReadStreamPng: converting (cmap + alpha) ==> RGBA
Info in pixReadStreamPng: converting 8 bpp cmap with alpha ==> RGBA
41-1-8 5
```

and also:

```
[root@usa1 ~]# tesseract cap.png cap -psm 7 digits && cat cap.txt
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00dev with Leptonica
Info in pixReadStreamPng: converting (cmap + alpha) ==> RGBA
Info in pixReadStreamPng: converting 8 bpp cmap with alpha ==> RGBA
7 5
```

The captcha sample is :

[image: Captcha example]

The main goal is to achieve an accurate result, and also I noticed that running the same command twice wont make any difference on result so I wont be able to run it for example 3 times and compare the different results right? 
And as for empty page error I guess somehow i need to make the quality of png file higher, am I wrong?